# Perform some action Before Phone locks

Tags: android

Is it possible to do some action/calculation when user locks an android device .ie when user locks device , before phone getting locked , my code should run.
I have used below intent on a broadcastreceiver , but it didn't work.

```
if (intent.getAction().equals(Intent.ACTION_SCREEN_OFF)) {

        }
```

Comment: Are you sure you registered it properly?

Comment: yeah , the same receiver works for
 if (intent.getAction().equals(Intent.ACTION_USER_PRESENT)) {